# R - Select all rows that have one NA value at most?

Tags: r, dataframe, na, imputation

I'm trying to impute my data and keep as many observations as I can. I want to select observations that have 1 `NA` value at most from the data found at: `mlbench::data(PimaIndiansDiabetes2)`.

For example:

```
Var1 Var2 Var3
1      NA   NA
2      34   NA
3      NA   NA
4      NA   55
5      NA   NA
6      40   28
```

What I would like returned:

```
Var1 Var2 Var3
2      34   NA
4      NA   55
6      40   28
```

This code returns rows with `NA` values and I know that I could join all observations with 1 `NA` value using `merge()` to observations without `NA` values. I'm not sure how to do extract those though.

```
na_rows <- df[!complete.cases(df), ]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A `base` R solution:

```r
df[rowSums(is.na(df)) <= 1, ]
```

Its `dplyr` equivalent:

```r
library(dplyr)

df %>%
  filter(rowSums(is.na(pick(everything()))) <= 1)
```